# Leaking at top of rear door

Tags: gmc, water-leak, sierra

2006 GMC Siera Ext cab.
I have a leak. water leaks in around the top of the left rear door. It appears to come down the rear door post. I have replaced the weather stripping and that didn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Could you post a picture of the leak area?  That might help get to the bottom here.

Answer (score 1):

Is the top of the door closing properly? if the top of the door is not compressing the seal sufficiently it will leak.

You could, with the window down, gently bend the door top in towards the car a small amount to increase the compression on the sealing strip, but be careful - does not need much...

Comment: A good test to see if this is necessary is to close a dollar bill in the door and try to pull it out. There should be noticable resistance.  Try this at different points around the seal.